# Next.js: prevent Showing index page before redirecting to Keycloak Login page

Tags: reactjs, next.js, keycloak

I've been working on Next.js project which authenticates with a Keycloak.

I used '@react-keycloak/ssr' library to implement frontend authentication.

Here's my _app.js code (Code Reference: https://github.com/react-keycloak/react-keycloak-examples/tree/master/examples/nextjs-app)

```
import cookie from 'cookie'
import * as React from 'react'
import type { IncomingMessage } from 'http'
import type { AppProps, AppContext } from 'next/app'

import { SSRKeycloakProvider, SSRCookies } from '@react-keycloak/ssr'

const keycloakCfg = {
  url: 'http://myauthurl/auth',
  realm: 'myrealm',
  clientId: 'myclientid',
}



interface InitialProps {
  cookies: unknown
}

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps, cookies }: AppProps & InitialProps) {
  const initOptions = {
    onLoad: 'login-required',
    checkLoginIframe: false
  }

  return (
    <SSRKeycloakProvider
      keycloakConfig={keycloakCfg}
      persistor={SSRCookies(cookies)}
      initOptions={initOptions}
    >
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </SSRKeycloakProvider>
  )
}

function parseCookies(req?: IncomingMessage) {
  if (!req || !req.headers) {
    return {}
  }
  return cookie.parse(req.headers.cookie || '')
}

MyApp.getInitialProps = async (context: AppContext) => {
  // Extract cookies from AppContext
  return {
    cookies: parseCookies(context?.ctx?.req),
  }
}

export default MyApp
```

My goal was to redirect unauthenticated users to keycloak login page. It worked by adding 'initOptions'. However, before redirecting, application shows index page for one second.

EDIT:
After writing code checks the state of authentication, I managed to hide components for users who are not logged in. However, after login success application shows blank page and keycloak is undefined.

```
import type { AppProps, AppContext } from "next/app";
import { SSRKeycloakProvider, useKeycloak } from "@react-keycloak/ssr";
import { Provider } from "urql";
import {
  keycloakConfig,
  initOptions,
  getPersistor,
  Keycloak,
} from "../libs/keycloak";
import { parseCookies } from "../libs/cookie";
import { useMemo } from "react";
import { createUrqlClient, ssrCache } from "../libs/urql";

interface Props extends AppProps {
  cookies: unknown;
  token?: string;
}

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps, cookies, token }: Props) {
  const urqlClient = useMemo(() => createUrqlClient(token), [token]);
  const {keycloak} = useKeycloak
  console.log(keycloak) //undefined after login success
  console.log(keycloak?.authenticated  ) //undefined after login success
  // SSR cache for urql
  if (pageProps?.urqlState) {
    ssrCache.restoreData(pageProps.urqlState);
  }
  return (
    <SSRKeycloakProvider
      keycloakConfig={keycloakConfig}
      persistor={getPersistor(cookies)}
      initOptions={initOptions}
    >
      <Provider value={urqlClient}>
        {keycloak?.authenticated && <Component {...pageProps} /> }
      </Provider>
    </SSRKeycloakProvider>
  );
}

MyApp.getInitialProps = async (context: AppContext) => {
  const keycloak = Keycloak(context?.ctx?.req);

  return {
    cookies: parseCookies(context?.ctx?.req),
    token: keycloak.token,
  };
};
export default MyApp;
```

Comment: It has to wait for a split seconds since it needs to check for authentication.. what is your desire behavior?

Comment: @Someone Special  Thank you for your answer! My desire behavior is if user enters url (localhost:3000) -> check authentication -> if not logged in redirect to keycloak login page. As I said in question, redirection  is okay but before showing login page index page slightly exposed.

Comment: checking of authentication is async, you need time to check. Check out answer below. You can alternative use `keycloak?.authenticated ? <CustomComponent /> : null` so it will not display anything

Comment: @Someone special Thank you for your suggestion! I don’t want any page to be shown before authentication so I tried to use                                 keycloak?.authenticated ?   <Component {...pageProps} /> : null.     Though keycloak was declared by calling useKeycloak(), keycloak is undefined.

Comment: you need to check your codes against the code i provided properly. This is because `keycloak?.authenticated` will not return undefined error since it uses optional chaining - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial Thanks to your suggestion, I managed to do what I was trying to do in my application. However, application cannot show any page(it only shows white blank page) after login success. I think it is because keycloak is undefined in _app.js. Could you please check the code from my edited question? Have I done something wrong?

Comment: Don't know it's a copy paste issue, but in the code you shared you're not calling useKeycloak correctly.

```js
const {keycloak} = useKeycloak
```

(you forgot the parentheses)

Anyway, did you find a solution by now? Having similar issues

Answer (score 2):

It has to wait for a split seconds since it needs to check for authentication.. what is your desire behavior?

You can use the `useKeycloak` hook in your page to show the behavior you want (e.g. Redirecting to login page....)

```
const IndexPage = () => {
  const { keycloak } = useKeycloak<KeycloakInstance>()

  const loggedinState = keycloak?.authenticated ? (
    <span className="text-success">logged in</span>
  ) : (
    <span className="text-danger">NOT logged in</span>
  )

  const welcomeMessage =
    keycloak?.authenticated 
      ? `Welcome back!`
      : 'Welcome visitor. Please login to continue.'

  return (
    <Layout title="Home | Next.js + TypeScript Example">
      <h1 className="mt-5">Hello Next.js + Keycloak </h1>
      <div className="mb-5 lead text-muted">
        This is an example of a Next.js site using Keycloak.
      </div>

      <p>You are: {loggedinState}</p>
      <p>{welcomeMessage}</p>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default IndexPage
```

Simplified example from https://github.com/react-keycloak/react-keycloak-examples/blob/master/examples/nextjs-app/pages/index.tsx